# Why does the word gobs mean a copious amount?

Tags: etymology, slang

Gobs is a word I've never seen in print; however, I've heard it used in an old moving picture and in an old situation comedy. I'm curious to know the origin of the word gobs as well as when it was first used to mean a copious amount.

I heard it used in the 1930 moving picture *Ladies of Leisure* when Marie Prevost is ordering a meal at a restaurant and tells the server she'd like "gobs of cheese" on her dish (I believe it was cheese). The next time I heard it used was in an episode of *Three's Company* "Ground Rules" which aired in 1977. Jack Tripper is with a young lady at the Regal Beagle and tells her "we can have gobs of fun here."

Those are the two examples I have for hearing gobs used to mean a copious amount. Any ideas for why gobs is slang for a copious amount and any ideas as to when it was first used or which decade/decades it was most popular.

Comment: 'Why' is a difficult question to answer. It just _is_. Or rather all there is to the explanation might be a history. It's not a reason for the path, just what the path is. Maybe you want to know why 'gobs' (as in 'a lot of') is similar sounding to 'gob' as in 'mouth'. That is (possibly) an answerable question.

Comment: It should be noted that "gob" is also a term of, uh, indistinction for a sailor.

Comment: (I can certainly attest that "Great green gobs of greasy grimy gopher guts" has been popular with a certain audience since the 50s, at least.)

Comment: @HotLicks I find it very hard to believe that gopher guts—of any description, however alliterative—are popular with any non-scavenger audience…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Not even 13-year-old males?

Comment: Never seen it in print?  See here: https://www.ign.com/articles/2007/07/12/harry-potter-and-the-gobs-of-moolah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[gob, gobs](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gob)
n.

> Informal A large quantity. Often used in the plural: a gob of money; gobs of time.

It seems that the word has Gaulish (Celtic) origins {[The Online Etymology Dictionary:Gob{2}(n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Gob&searchmode=none)}:

> *"a mouthful, lump," late 14c., probably from Old French gobe "mouthful, lump,"* related to gober "gulp, swallow down," probably from Gaulish *gobbo- (compare Irish gob "mouth," Gaelic gob "beak"). *This Celtic source also seems to be root of gob "mouth" (mid-16c.), which is the first element in gob-stopper "a kind of large hard candy" (1928).*

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gob%20of%20,%20gobs%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,gob%20of;,c0;.t1;,gobs%20of;,c0) shows an increasing usage of the expression *gobs of* since the beginning of the 20th century.

Answer (score 2):

As listed under [gob](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gob?s=t)

350–1400; Middle English gobbe,  variant of gobet gobbet...

...where gobbet:
1275–1325; Middle English gobet  < Old French:  a mouthful, diminutive of gobe.

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gob?s=t

Answer (score 1):

Although previous answers may have suggested that this is not the case, there is actually no accepted etymology for the colloquial word gob (also, gab) "mouth". Skeat (on page 238 of *An etymological dictionary of the English language* https://archive.org/stream/etymologicaldict00skeauoft#page/238/mode/2up) stated baldly that "the provincial English gob, the mouth, is borrowed from Celtic directly". He was referring ultimately to an lrish word, gop, which is defined by the Dictionary of the Irish language as "muzzle, snout, beak".

An alternative derivation suggests itself when we examine the distribution map of dialect words for the notion mouth in Orton and Wright's "A Word Geography of England" (a work based on the Survey of English Dialects), where we see that the word "gob" is found in Yorkshire, County Durham, Westmoreland, the northern parts of Derbyshire and Lincolnshire, and in an area of Norfolk, i.e. almost exactly the Danelaw area.

This suggests that, as an alternative to the Celtic hypothesis, we should seek a Scandinavian origin for the word. And we don't have to look far, as one of the terms for the notion "mouth" in modern Danish is the word "gab". Hence it was surely Scandinavian settlers who brought the words gob and gab to England. Cognates also exist in modern Swedish and modern Norwegian "gap", and this is the form the word had in Old Norse, the period we should assume the word was introduced to England. The nouns gob and gab are related to the modern English verb gape, (gapen in Middle English) which refers to the mouth, and is recorded as early as c. 1225. It's also been linked to the Old Norse verb "gapa" in the Oxford Dictionary of English Etymology.

Comment: Hello, bigbaddwolff. Could you please add the attribution for and a hotlink to the Skeat quote(?)

Comment: I felt that there was a contradiction when I read this:"there is actually no accepted etymology for the colloquial word gob" and then this: "it was surely Scandinavian settlers who brought the words gob and gab to England." If there's no accepted etymology, why present this presumably speculative one as a sure thing?

Comment: Your proposed etymology is not without its problems. First off, there’s the question of the vowel: where did English get its _o_ from, when the Nordic languages all unanimous have _a_ throughout (nowhere in the entire complex of words derived from the root found in the _gape_ verb is there an _o_ in any Norse languages, as far as I know)? And secondly, where did English get its _b_ from? The voicing of the /p/ to /b/ in Danish postdates attestations of the word (with /b/) in English, and Danish (+ some Norwegian dialects) is the only Nordic language to have a _b_ at all there.

Comment: Let me recant part of that: _gob_ is attested in English with a ⟨b⟩ before the time when _gap_ became _gab_ in Danish, but only in the sense ‘mass/lump’, which is from Old French. The ‘mouth’ sense is later than the Danish voicing of postvocalic /p/ to /b/, but this voicing still happened a good deal after the Danelaw ceased to exist and Danish was replaced by Norman French as the major influence on English vocabulary. At the time of the Danelaw, it would still have been _gap_ in Danish, which is a fair bit from _gob_ in English (not attested until about four centuries later).

Comment: Incidentally, it’s also worth noting that (at least Modern) Irish also has _geab_ (also _gab_) meaning ‘talk, chatter’, which fits very well with the English word _gab_, attested since the 1800s.

Comment: @ sumelic....my use of the adverb "surely" implies that my alternative hypothesis is exactly that and not a "sure thing".                                                                    @ Janus ...you could well be right. We should also bear in mind that a large number of Norwegian settlers/raiders came to Ireland in the late 8th century, my ancestors actually, which further confuses the situation. I've found that many people across the Irish sea are over keen to claim English words as their own, when in fact when in fact the reality is far more unclear,

Comment: @bigbaddwolff True; but a change from Norse /p/ to Irish /b/ would also be strange. Had it been Welsh, it would be possible (intervocalic lenition of unvoiced plosives gives voices plosives in Welsh), but not Irish (where the same process yields unvoiced fricatives, so if Norse _gap_ were borrowed and changed at all, it would give _gaph_ [gaf]).

Comment: (Also, for @-pinging to work in comments, there must be no space after the @, otherwise the people you're pinging won't be notified.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth...OK, added it.

Comment: @sumelic....surely my use of the adverb "surely" implies that my alternative hypothesis is exactly that and not a "sure thing"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where it originated, but I grew up with "heaps and gobbs" as a common phrase in central Illinois in the 70s and 80s. I never considered that it was not a regular part of American English until I was bored and just started googling it. There is a strong Irish-German cultural presence in the area, so perhaps it is from a Gaelic phrase. An example would be a child saying to her mother, "I love you heaps and gobbs." Or, maybe, as an answer to are you hungry? "I could eat heaps and gobbs!"